# changing laravel vps hosting caused HTTP ERROR 500 on submitting [$_POST] login/signup page

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, nginx, http-status-code-500

The website is in Laravel 5.2.45 with Postgres.

The old VPS configuration is CentOs 7 with PHP 7.0, nginx/1.20.1, Composer version 1.9.0,   PostgreSQL

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
```

.

The new VPS configuration is CentOs 7 with PHP 7.1, nginx/1.20.1, Composer version 2.2.12,  PostgreSQL

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.2
```

After making a transfer of the files using  ()

```
rsync -avz /srv/www/ root@host:/srv/www
```

For the database transfer, "**pg_dump**" is used to back up the old database, and "**pg_restore**" is used to restore to the new database. The scripts are

```
pg_dump -F t old_db > old_db.tar 
pg_restore --dbname=new_db --verbose old_db.tar
```

I dare to upgrade from PostgreSQL version 9 to 14 based on this article:
[The  pg_restore can take a database backed up in the older version and restore it in the newer version.](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-restore-database/)

Successfully updated composer, done with firewall-cmd, SeLinux setup

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/srv/www(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv /srv/www
```

after these setups, the website is accessible fine. But when I try to log in (admin or user) or sign up, I'm getting

```
This page isn’t working
www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

In the Nginx access_log, getting the following response

```
[19/Apr/2022:06:52:35 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/2.0" 500 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
```

There is neither entry for this event in Nginx error_log, nor anything in the Laravel_log

If anyone knows the reason behind this behavior. Please, I need your appreciable guide to solve this.

Appendix:

-> I have also installed and set the pgadmin4 with apache on a distinct port xxxxxx  on the new VPS.

-> **The old server is still intact and is able to get the website fine for all things.**

-> Don't think composer version mismatch could be the reason.

Comment: could also check the /var/log/syslog for any clues

Comment: Check the file permissions (for the laravel log file especially) to debug this.

Comment: @apokryfos are you indicating the default nginx logs? There is also nothing.

Comment: @N69S laravel_root/storage directories have rwxrwxswx 777, and files have rw-r--r--

Comment: Syslog is the default system log, also try setting the default log driver to syslog in laravel in case there's issues with other log drivers

Comment: @PrashantKumarKashyap, what is your nginx config first? There should be more explanation in `error.log` if you didn't switch it off.

Comment: The problem is with SELinux settings. Somehow i managed to fix the issue. But i'm thinking to disable SELinux, It seems to be very tricky to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.php in

> bootstrap/cache

for any data mismatch and old data from old server. you can easily update config.php to current new state.

Comment: There is no config.php file in bootstrap/cache. rather there is a services.php file in there.